# Inconsistent (buggy?) combined flair behavior when reputation is exactly 200

Tags: support, bug, reputation-graph, combined-flair

As we know, my [combined flair](https://stackexchange.com/users/flair/1988549.png) has only the SE accounts with at least 200 reputation, and the [reputation graph](https://stackexchange.com/users/1988549/peter-horvath?tab=reputation) in my SE has this accounts only.

I have exactly 200 reputation on [http://unix.stackexchange.com](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/52236/peter-horvath).

The behavior of the flair & my SE account:

1. The icon of the site *doesn't appear* in my combined flair.
2. But the combined reputation in the flair *contains* my unix.stackexchange.com reputation.
3. My [combined reputation graph in my SE statistics page](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/52236/peter-horvath) *doesn't contain* my unix SE reputation history.

Is it a consistent behavior of the system? Maybe somewhere there is a "`>200`" and somewhere "`>=200`" in the SE source code?

*Extension:* Recently I stepped through the reputation 200 on [space SE](https://space.stackexchange.com) as well, and I experienced the same behavior. In case of a real problem, I really suggest a fix. AFAIK the combined reputation graph generating code has a 200 and the combined flair graph has a 201 somewhere in the code. Dear SE, maybe you think it is not a major bug on the first spot, but actually, it is. Because a psychological effect: reaching 200 is an important part in a new SE site, and the interval between 100 and 200 is hard (far fewer people want give vote for you).

Comment: At most 7 site icons get shown on the flair. Not sure I understand your last point.

Comment: @Mat Thank you for (1). I extended (3) with a link, maybe so is it clearer.

Comment: I think this is one of the cases where "minimum of 200 reputation" actually means "201 or above". :(

Comment: @ShadowWizard Thank you! Maybe a single change in the needed repu weren't really hard, if it is really a bug (or at least inconsistent behavior).

Comment: I reached 200 on electronics SE as well ( https://electronics.stackexchange.com/users/35118/peter-horvath ), and I am experiencing further the same inconsistent behavior.

Comment: UPDATE: I've [checked this now again](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/300276/152859), and users with exactly 200 rep appear to have the site in the combined flair.