# Combined flair minimum reputation description is inaccurate

Tags: feature-request, design, combined-flair

According to the text explaining combined profile flair (emphasis mine):

> (please note that only sites where you have **more than 200 reputation** will appear, and that flair is only updated once every 24-36 hours.)
>
> [image: My flair]

[image: profile for ryanyuyu on Stack Exchange, a network of free, community-driven Q&A sites]

At the time of this posting, my reputation on world building is exactly 200 (which is not *more than* 200 reputation), yet it still appears on my flair.  I don't think I'm experiencing this other [(unresolved?) bug for hitting exactly 200 reputation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/231976/280467) where the community is inconsistent in appearing on the combined flair.

### Feature request:

Please update the explanation to something like (emphasis mine, to show the wording change):

> (please note that only sites where you have **at least 200 reputation** will appear, and that flair is only updated once every 24-36 hours.)

Comment: It's not just when you have exactly 200 rep, I have 3 sites showing on my combined flair with < 200 rep, including Mathematics where I only have 101 rep.